# Как победить JS ошибку Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .main_menu .menu li > a[href*=#]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как победить JS ошибку `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .main_menu .menu li > a[href*=#]`? Возникает в файле jquery.js на этой [странице](http://ruchnoe-razmeschenie.ru/shop/uslugi/30-dosok-obyavlenij/) и в целом по [сайту](http://ruchnoe-razmeschenie.ru/).

Comment: Начать стоит с поиска по html и js файлам места, где используется данный селектор. Когда найдёте, попробуйте изменить его на `.main_menu .menu li > a[href*="#"]`.

Answer (score 5):

Неправильный синтаксис селектора атрибутов для тегов `<a>` : верный формат должен быть таким `[атрибут="значение"] { Описание правил стиля }` - следовательно, в селекторе упущены кавычки, в которых должно указываться значение.

`a[href*="#"]` - верно

<del>`a[href*=#]`</del> - неверно

Более подробно можно почитать по ссылке: [Селекторы атрибутов](https://webref.ru/css/selector/attr2)